# Create views of node reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have two types of content:

Reports and customers

The type of reports has a field content "node reference" which can include multiple customers.

Each time you click a content type of reports already created, within the node of such a view with me content customers that report should appear.

How can i create this view which shows me only the reference node to enter a specific content type reports.

thanks

Comment: Do you care to share your current configuration in form of images?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well (you want to display all customers referenced from currently viewed report) then for that you don't need a view at all. From your template file for reports content type (node--reports.tpl.php or something) you already gave the array of referenced customers.

I.e. if you called your node reference field "customers" your array should be accessible with:

```
$node->field_customers['und']
```

If that doesn't help just print_r whole $node object to see what you have there and how to access it:

```
print_r($node); // from your node template file
```

Comment: If I print the variable in the file content type reports , this brings me only titles, but I really need other information .

Comment: If you have node id's you can use node_load() to use whole customer node.